# Do automatic variables have lifetime equal to that of a static variable (within the same block)?

Tags: c

I know that it's a silly question to ask, but please indulge me for a bit.

What do I know?

- Scope of a variable `x` is basically the block within which `x` was defined. If `x` belongs to the 
  automatic storage class then, it can only be used within the block where it was declared (which is precisely the scope of `x`).
- Lifetime of a variable `x` is basically the time period during which `x` is allowed to live in the memory. And if `x` is an automatic variable then, by default it'll be killed as soon as it's scope is executed.

So, why do I have this question? 
It is because of the following code I accidentally conjured.

```
#include<stdio.h>
void scratch(void);
int main(void)
{
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                scratch();
        return 0;
}
void scratch(void)
{
        static int static_var = 0;
        int auto_var1, auto_var2 = 0;
        printf("[info] 'static' variable = %d | 'auto' variable 1 = %d | 'auto' variable 2 = %d\n", static_var++, auto_var1++, auto_var2);
}
```

Output:

```
[info] 'static' variable = 0 | 'auto' variable 1 = 0 | 'auto' variable 2 = 0
[info] 'static' variable = 1 | 'auto' variable 1 = 1 | 'auto' variable 2 = 0
[info] 'static' variable = 2 | 'auto' variable 1 = 2 | 'auto' variable 2 = 0
[info] 'static' variable = 3 | 'auto' variable 1 = 3 | 'auto' variable 2 = 0
[info] 'static' variable = 4 | 'auto' variable 1 = 4 | 'auto' variable 2 = 0
```

The static variable, `static_var` does it's job perfectly well. However, notice the behavior of both automatic variables : `auto_var1` & `auto_var2`. According to my understanding of automatic variables, both `auto_var1` & `auto_var2` should have printed `0` in each iteration, because their lifetime should have ended the moment `scratch()` returned to `main()`. But looks like these guys are living a long life. So my question is why? Does this mean that an automatic variable also has a lifetime equal to that of static variable in the same block? OR is it a compiler based issue?

Note : The above code was compiled via `gcc version 7.2.0` on Ubuntu 17. Also, a request to everyone who attempts to answer this question : kindly stick to `C` for answering.

Comment: Undefined behavior.

Comment: if the static variable is destroyed after going out of the function then how can its value be retained the next time you call the function?

Comment: @phuclv, for static variables I believe that, they live for as long as the program exists. However they can only be used within their scope. And because they've a long life, therefore they're able to retain their values beyond their scope.

Comment: The value of the uninitialized variable `auto_var1` is indeterminate, and using an indeterminate value results in undefined behaviour in C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do automatic variables have lifetime equal to that of a static
>   variable (within the same block)?

Short answer - No, an object with automatic storage duration is limited to the block within which it is declared. An object with static storage duration remains valid for the life of the program. See [C11 Standard - 6.2.4 Storage durations of objects](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.4)

Now within the same block, from the standpoint of either object, both remain valid for the life of the block. The one with automatic storage duration will simply cease to be accessible after leaving the block while the one with static storage duration can be accessed elsewhere.

Comment: Considering the fact that an automatic variable's scope is also it's lifetime, how can one describe the ability of 'auto_var1' to retain it's value outside of it's lifetime? Or should I simply consider it as an undefined behaviour, as mentioned by @jxh?

Comment: `auto_var1` can never retain is value outside its lifetime ***In a way that is legal to access it***. The memory is released for reuse. Whether it has been overwritten yet or not is irrelevant -- you cannot access a variable outside its lifetime for that reason - no guarantee - invokes *Undefined Behavior*. `"If an object is referred to outside of its lifetime, the behavior is undefined."` (6.2.4(p2))

Comment: Okay. Now I get it. The reason, why `auto_var1` was able to retain it's value even past it's life was only because there was no overwriting performed at it's memory location. So, this brings me to the question, shouldn't `auto_var1` have been reallocated with new memory location every time `scratch()` gets called? Why reallocate it with the same memory location?

Comment: YEP!!! Bingo... The value is still there -- but you can't legally access it -- no guarantee it will be there. So we treat every variable that goes out of scope as untouchable...

Comment: @Argon - the last piece of the puzzle you are missing is that every time `scratch()` is called, a separate *Function Stack* is created, and all local variables are declared within that block of memory. When the function returns, the function stack is released for re-use. So every call to `scratch()` is a new and separate function stack setup (now does that mean the compiler cannot be smart enough to optimize that somehow to minimize system resources -- of course it can -- but how and whether the compiler optimizes some aspects of the call isn't something the standard allows you to rely on.)

Comment: So, it is safe to assume that reallocation of memory happens every time `scratch()` gets called, but just because during the reallocation the old values weren't erased, we end up sometimes getting the same memory block and thus the same old values. So this was the main reason why my `auto_var1` was fortunate enough to retain it's value.

Comment: Yes. The compiler can look at repeated calls to a function and if there are no side-effects to the function it is free to optimize all calls to a single function stack setup (or optimize the whole thing out), or do anything in between so long as the behavior of the program complies with what the standard guarantees. That is the whole rub between "Defined" behavior and "Undefined Behavior". When behavior is defined, you are guaranteed a defined result, otherwise the behavior is *"like a box of chocolates -- you never know what you are going to get..."* `:)`

Comment: And with this, my entire puzzle of storage classes have been solved. Thank you for indulging me @David C. Rankin!

Comment: Good glad to help. Keep the link to the standard handy (that is one of the only "html" C11 standards available). The standard is a bit cryptic at first, but after you stumble through the sections a couple of times, you figure out where things live in it, and it is the gospel of what you can or can't do in C. (it's also vague enough in places, that it leaves a bit of wiggle-room). You are taking to correct approach to understanding C at the level it needs to be understood. Keep up the good work. You never really learn it all, it's the continually learning a bit more that will serve you well.

Comment: Re “cease to be accessible after leaving the block”: No. An automatic object without variable length array type ceases to exist when execution of its associated block **ends**, not when execution **leaves** the block. Execution may leave the block via a function call or signal handler (and other threads may be executing simultaneously and may also be able to access the object). These suspend but do not end execution of the block, and the object continues to exist.

Comment: Re “elsewhere”: No. It is easy to tell when one has mixed up scope and lifetime. Scope is **where** an **identifier** is visible. Lifetime is **when** an **object** exists. Anything saying “where” an object exists is wrong. An object that exists can be accessed any**where** in the program, regardless of the scope of its identifier (subject to other constraints, such as limits on defined behavior regarding unsequenced accesses, accesses from signal handlers, and so on).

Comment: @EricPostpischil the elsewhere meant the static variable's lifetime is for the life of the program and will be preserved for in the next call to `scratch()`.

Comment: The word for something that can be accessed at any time during program execution is “anytime”, not “elsewhere”. Both automatic and static objects can be accessed anywhere in the program.

Answer (score 1):

First variable is not initialized, you are printing garbage there.

```
int auto_var1, auto_var2 = 0;
```

Change this to initialize both, they'll both print 0 then.

```
int auto_var1 = 0, auto_var2 = 0;
```

Comment: Agreed. However, what  can you say about their lifetime?

Answer (score 1):

The other answers tell you what you should do according to the C standard, I'll explain why it happens to work as it does.

In order to keep track of where functions should return and the values of their automatic variables, most platforms define a data structure called [the stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack), which may be grown or shrunk at one end. When a function `f` calls another function `g`, first a return address is pushed onto the stack and then `g`'s automatic variables are created on the stack. When `g` returns, it deallocates its automatic variables and pops the return address from the stack and jumps to it, returning the stack to its state before the function call.

In your `scratch` function, `auto_var1` is not initialised, so when the variable is created, nothing is written to it; it contains whatever happened to appear in that place in memory. The first time `scratch` was called, it happened to contain zero, so it was incremented to 1, and then the variable was destroyed. In subsequent calls, however, the stack layout is exactly the same as the first time `scratch` was called and so `auto_var1` was allocated in the same place where it was before. Since the variable is still not initialised, the value is incremented again, and the variable appears to behave as if it was static.

Now, it's only by sheer luck that this works this way: it's because the stack layout is exactly the same in each call. If for example you had a call `main` → `scratch` and then `main` → `func` → `scratch`, this would no longer be the case. And even the above explanation is still somewhat simplified; for example, the compiler may choose to keep a variable in a [CPU register](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_register) instead of the stack, and reuse the register between function calls, so even keeping the call graph the same does not guarantee it working this way.

Even aside from all that, the code still exhibits undefined behaviour according to the C standard. The compiler is not guaranteed to preserve this behaviour in different circumstances, and it is not portable to different architectures; on some, like Itanium, the code may outright crash. Uninitialised memory is not even guaranteed to be 'stable': reading the same address more than once may yield different values each time.

Moral of the story: initialise your variables before reading them.

Comment: Thankyou for adding this perspective to the picture. Helped me to shape my entire thought process.

Answer (score 0):

The value of `auto_var1` shows undefined behavior where it seems the variable keeps its value between function calls and gets incremented, just as the static variable does.

If you are running on Intel then this can be explained as follows:

The for loop does not change the stack and each time it calls function `scratch()` it modifies the stack in *the same way* by pushing return address, saving registers and then incrementing the stack pointer to create room for the local variables `int auto_var1` and `auto_var2`. The second one is initialized to zero, the first one is not initialized, so the value in that memory location (variable) *is the same as from the previous function call.* The memory location gets incremented and the function returns. The next iteration increments it again and again.

The only point to notice is that in one or another way, the memory location was zero on the first iteration. This is a coincidence.